# Delete from two mysql tables at once using join codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to delete from two mysql tables at once using this function.

```
public function deleteBusiness($id)
        {
            $this->db->from("business");
            $this->db->join("opening_hours", "business");
            $this->db->where("business", $id);
            return $this->db->delete(array("business","opening_hours"));
        }
```

It appears to be working correctly, as the correct data is being deleted from both tables, but when I call it with the following...

```
if($this->businesses_model->deleteBusiness($id)){
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'Business Deleted');
                } else {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'There was a problem deleting that business');
                }
```

the failed error message is being displayed.

Comment: and what is the return from `$this->db->error()` (assuming CodeIgniter 3.0+)  ?

Comment: I have instead used foreign key constraints between the tables. I don't know why I didn't try this sooner!!

Answer (score 0):

Replace Above code with Following Code let me know if does not work

```
public function deleteBusiness($id)
 {
            $this->db->from("business");
            $this->db->join("opening_hours", "business");
            $this->db->where("business", $id);
            $this->db->delete(array("business","opening_hours"));
            return $this->db->affected_rows();
 }


if($this->businesses_model->deleteBusiness($id) > 0){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'Business Deleted');
   } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'There was a problem deleting that business');
   }
```

let me know if it does not work

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. I haven't tried this, but the line return $this->db->affected_rows(); looks like it might have been what I was missing.

Comment: I have instead used foreign key constraints between the tables. I don't know why I didn't try this sooner!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to Delete a row from `business` table and all the rows in the `opening_hours` related to that business.

Unfortunately your code will not work as `CodeIgniter` ignores joins when doing Active Record deletes.

Their Documentation does says that you can pass an array to delete method and it will delete from multiple rows

```
$tables = array('table1', 'table2', 'table3');
$this->db->where('id', '5');
$this->db->delete($tables);
```

However, please see that it will delete rows from 3 tables where `id` = 5. Same way in your case it will delete from business and opening_hours where id is say 2. Obviously this is not what you want.

Only option is to use either 2 queries like below or use a Raw SQL query.

```
            $this->db->from("business");
            $this->db->where("id", $id);
            $this->db->delete('business');

            $this->db->from("opening_hours");
            $this->db->where("business_id", $id);                       
            $this->db->delete('opening_hours');
```

Comment: I have instead used foreign key constraints between the tables. I don't know why I didn't try this sooner!!

Comment: Even if you want to use the Foreign Key Delete Constraint, you will have to make changes in your code to delete only business table.

Comment: Hi, if I delete a business, I also want to delete any corresponding entries in the opening ours table. I don't want an error to the leave opening hours after a business has been deleted. The foreign key constraints seem to work.